# Close all files in a shared directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a script that does the following

```
'Create a bat file
Set objBatFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("X:\" & strType & "\closeit.bat",True)
intExitCode = objBatFile.Write("for /f " & chr(34) & "skip=4 tokens=1" & chr(34) & " %%a in ('net files') do net files %%a /close")
objBatFile.Close
'Run the bat file to close all files in the directory
intExitCode = objShell.Run("X:\" & strType & "\closeit.bat", intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn)
StopStart
'Delete the bat file
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
obj.DeleteFile("X:\" & strType & "\closeit.bat") 'Deletes the file throught the DeleteFile function
```

I was wondering if any one knew of a way to use vbscript to replace the .bat file command I am using to close open files on the server? The line I want to replace is below for better clarity:

```
for /f " & chr(34) & "skip=4 tokens=1" & chr(34) & " %%a in ('net files') do net files %%a /close
```

Comment: Can't you do opposite? Replace entire VBS with batch?

Answer (score 1):

Execute `cmd`:

```
intExitCode = objShell.Run("CMD.EXE /C for /f ""skip=4 tokens=1"" %a in ('net files') do net files %a /close"), blnWaitOnReturn)
```

Note that `FOR` outside batch expects single `%` before variable.

You can replace `"+Chr(34)+"` with just `""` (at least in VBA and VB.NET).